# Pip won't install into python 3 when using homebrew python?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, pip, homebrew

So I've got a virtualenv I've created using `pyvenv-3.3`, which I thought set up `pip` to install things into the virtualenv's path. However, I get the following outputs after I've activated by virtualenv:

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

pip-3.3 --version
pip 1.4.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py3.3.egg (python 3.3)
```

This is all fine and good, but then my `sys.path` is this:

```
['',
'/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python33.zip', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/plat-darwin', 
'/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload',
'/Users/alexgolec/Documents/gutenberg/virtualenv/lib/python3.3/site-packages']
```

Most notably, the whole `site-packages` directory is outright missing. Furthermore, this output indicates to me that I'm probably using a python that installed through homebrew at some point. Most infuriatingly, none of the directories in my `sys.path` are compatible with pip.

Any thoughts on remedies? I won't manually edit my `sys.path`, but maybe there's some configuration with pip I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install virtualenvwrapper (makes using virtualenv so much easier):

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

.. and then try this:

```
mkvirtualenv <your_env> -p /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Where homebrew sticks python is different from where your system has it.  You can run the following to see what I'm talking about:

```
which python
which python3
```